# Different thread groups should pickup different user IDs from csv

Tags: jmeter

I have 20 thread groups and 100 users id csv file under test plan level.my requirement is each thread group need to pickup different user ID's like 1 st thread group need to pickup first 5 user ID's and 2 nd thread group need to pickup next 5 user IDs and 3 rd thread group need to pickup another 5 unique user ID's like so on.....20 th thread group need to last 5 user IDs.could anyone please let me know

Different thread group should pickup different unique user IDs from csv

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be just splitting the CSV file into 20 separate CSV files so each thread group would use its own file.

If the file comes from external source and you will have to split it each time you want to run the test you can automate it using [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) and [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler). Something like:

```
new File('test.csv').readLines().eachWithIndex { line, index ->
    new File('test_' + ((index % 5) + 1) + '.csv') << line << System.getProperty('line.separator')
}
```

Will split your `test.csv` file into 5 files called `test_1.csv`, `test_2.csv`, etc. each having 20 entries